# When I use the externals property of webpack to separate large libraries (such as React), browser reports an error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

My webpack configuration fragment

```
...
externals: {
    'react': 'React',
    'react-dom': 'ReactDOM',
    'react-router-dom': 'ReactRouterDom',
    'axios': 'axios'
},
...
```

HTML file

```html
<body>
    <section id="wrapper">
        <div id="loading"></div>
    </section>
    <script src="https://cdn.bootcss.com/react/16.4.0/cjs/react.production.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.bootcss.com/react-dom/16.4.0/cjs/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.bootcss.com/axios/0.18.0/axios.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.bootcss.com/react-router-dom/4.3.0-rc.3/react-router-dom.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

Browser error screenshot
[image]

I would like to ask how to solve this, I mainly want to compress the size of the vendors.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are trying to use common js builds for these libraries in browser. However, [common js](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CommonJS) only works in Node.JS and not in browsers.

Your best bet is to use UMD builds of these packages. I am not fully aware of how cdn.bootcss.com works, but if you were to use unpkg CDN, you should change your URLs like this:

```
    <body>
      <section id="wrapper">
        <div id="loading"></div>
      </section>
      <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16.4.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.4.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://unpkg.com/axios@0.18.0/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-router-dom@4.3.1/umd/react-router-dom.min.js"></script>
    </body>
```